# how to hide bottom black area when entering new activity from top of screen

Tags: android, android-activity, overridependingtransition

I am entering a new activity from top to bottom, while keeping the old still. Everything works fine, except that there is a black area at the bottom of the new entering activity, which does not look very nice (see the picture). The theme I am using is "Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

[image]

I suppose it is the space assigned to cope with the bottom navigation bar. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: code of what? Layout, java source...?

Answer (score 0):

Set a translucent theme for your activity , android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
OR
Add an exit animation too.

Comment: I need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with the activity

Comment: Add this in your theme <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>